# how to add version at static resources in my jsp

Tags: java, maven, jsp

like this in my jsp:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/xxx/xxx.css">
↓
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/xxx/xxx.css?ver=20160608">
```

should I use maven or other tools？

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven WAR plugin with filters configured. Example config:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
      </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <includes>
            <include>**/main.jsp</include>
          </includes>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

In your JSP you can add:

```
<link href="css/styles.css?version=@project.version@" rel="stylesheet"
    media="screen" />
```